# fillna(0) changing other values

Tags: python, pyspark

This is the frequency_creative dataframe

```
[('tags', 'int'), 
 ('user_id', 'bigint'), 
 ('processdate', 'date'), 
 ('brandsurvey_name', 'string'), 
 ('survey_id', 'string'), 
 ('questionid', 'string'), 
 ('questiontext', 'string'), 
 ('frequency', 'bigint'), 
 ('creative_id', 'string')]
```

When i use `fillna(0)` then some values of user_id column is getting corrupted.But,if `fillna(0)` is not used the things are working fine.

```
frequency_creative.select("user_id").distinct().show()

 +-------------------+
 |            user_id|
 +-------------------+
 |1665009053012894694|
 | 840031193618494976|
 +-------------------+


frequency_creative  =frequency_creative.select("processdate","tags","survey_id","brandsurvey_name","user_id","questionid","questiontext","frequency","creative_id").fillna(0)
frequency_creative.select("user_id").distinct().show()

after select
+-------------------+
|            user_id|
+-------------------+
|1665009053012894720|
| 840031193618494976|
+-------------------+
**********************************************
without fillna(0)


before select
+-------------------+
|            user_id|
+-------------------+
|1665009053012894694|
| 840031193618494976|
+-------------------+

frequency_creative  =frequency_creative.select("processdate","tags","survey_id","brandsurvey_name","user_id","questionid","questiontext","frequency","creative_id")
frequency_creative.select("user_id").distinct().show()

after select
+-------------------+
|            user_id|
+-------------------+
|1665009053012894694|
| 840031193618494976|
+-------------------+
```

Comment: user_id is `monotonically_increasing_id` ?

Comment: Since the ids are changing, it seems to be as @Steve suggests that the user_id is created by `monotonically_increasing_id`. Which means, if you do not cache the dataframe, each time you perform an action the ids might be recreated. Try separating the creation of the dataframe from the fillna and cache the intermediate dataframe, e.g.: `frequency_creative  = frequency_creative.select("processdate","tags","survey_id","brandsurvey_name","user_id","questionid","questiontext","frequency","creative_id").cache()` and then `frequency_creative =  frequency_creative.fillna(0)`

Comment: user_id are **not** monotonically_increasing_id .

Comment: @J.S Is user_id created somehow? Or do you read it from specific data?

Comment: @mkaran read it from specific data.